# Insert `dynamic` object into MongoDB in .NET

Tags: .net, mongodb, json.net, .net-4.5, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a dynamic object being used as a parameter on a `ApiController`.  e.e:

```
public class Shape
{
    public dynamic Coordinates { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The coordinates for any shape are different, a circle will have a centre and radius, a line has an x1, y1, x2, y2 etc.

I am trying to store this object in Mongo.

What I am hoping for is:

```
{
    "Shapes": [
        {
            "Coordinates": {
                    "x1": 1,
                    "y1": 2,
                    "x2": 3,
                    "y2": 4
                }
            },
            "Type": "line"
        },
        {
            "Coordinates": "{ "x" : 10, "y" : 20, "r" : 30,},
            "Type": "circle"
        }
    ],
}
```

When I use `BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(coordinates)` I get

```
{
    "Shapes": [
        {
            "Coordinates": "{ \"x1\" : [], \"y1\" : [], \"x2\" : [], \"y2\" : [] }",
            "Type": "line"
        }
    ],
}
```

When I use `(JObject) coordinates` I get:

```
{
    "Shapes": [
        {
            "Coordinates": {
                "_t": "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
                "_v": {
                    "x1": [

                    ],
                    "y1": [

                    ],
                    "x2": [

                    ],
                    "y2": [

                    ]
                }
            },
            "Type": "line"
        }
    ],
}
```

I'd rather not haver to resort to storing it as a string.  How do I convince .NET that I want to store the dynamic object's values?

Comment: Would you mind pasting the code that creates and populates and instance of the Shape class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic type is not support by MongoDB C# driver so far, sadly. But it is planned to be included in `v2.0`.

> Probably towards the end of year, likely in conjunction with server 2.6.

You could track this issue here and vote for this feature.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-539

Answer (score 0):

Having done something similar in a different NoSQL  database (FatDB) that has a similar issue,   have you considered using JSON.NET to serialize it to a string and simply store the string in a class?

If you use an ExpandoObject (a type of dynamic object), you should be able to serialize it, toss the results into a string that goes into MongoDB and pull it out later on using a uniqueId.  I have not tried that specifically with MongoDB, but at that point your dynamic object is nothing more than  a string.  When you pull it out, you de-serialize the JSON and you have your ExpandoObject back.